# How to rotate an image to align the text for extraction?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using pytessearct to extract the text from images. But it doesn't work on images which are inclined. Consider the image given below:

[image]

Here is the code to extract text, which is working fine on images which are not inclined.

```
img = cv2.imread(<path_to_image>)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
ret3, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
def findSignificantContours (img, edgeImg):
    contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(edgeImg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    # Find level 1 contours
    level1 = []
    for i, tupl in enumerate(heirarchy[0]):
        # Each array is in format (Next, Prev, First child, Parent)
        # Filter the ones without parent
        if tupl[3] == -1:
            tupl = np.insert(tupl, 0, [i])
            level1.append(tupl)
    significant = []
    tooSmall = edgeImg.size * 5 / 100 # If contour isn't covering 5% of total area of image then it probably is too small
    for tupl in level1:
        contour = contours[tupl[0]];
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > tooSmall:
            significant.append([contour, area])
        # Draw the contour on the original image
        cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0,255,0),2, cv2.LINE_AA, maxLevel=1)

    significant.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    #print ([x[1] for x in significant]);
    mx = (0,0,0,0)      # biggest bounding box so far
    mx_area = 0
    for cont in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
        area = w*h
        if area > mx_area:
            mx = x,y,w,h
            mx_area = area
            x,y,w,h = mx

  # Output to files
    roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
    ret3, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2_imshow(thresh)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi); 
    print(text); print("\n"); print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh));
    print("\n")
    return [x[0] for x in significant];

edgeImg_8u = np.asarray(thresh, np.uint8)

# Find contours
significant = findSignificantContours(img, edgeImg_8u)
mask = thresh.copy()
mask[mask > 0] = 0
cv2.fillPoly(mask, significant, 255)
# Invert mask
mask = np.logical_not(mask)

#Finally remove the background
img[mask] = 0;
```

Tesseract can't extract the text from this image. Is there a way I can rotate it to align the text perfectly and then feed it to pytesseract? Please let me know if my question require any more clarity.

Comment: You can get the Rotated Rectangle and angle of the card. Use the angle to straighten the rotation and feed that image into Tesseract.

Comment: Yes, I found the rectangle and the countours array. How do I form the rectangle out of it? It would be great if you can suggest me something. @eldesgraciado

Comment: It is not the contour bounding rectangle that you want. You need to use cv2.minAreaRect() to find the rotated rectangle from which you can get the center, width and height and rotation. You can use the rotation to rectify your image. See the docs at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9. See also https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load image](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html), convert to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html),
   [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Find contours and sort for largest contour**. We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then filter using contour area with [`cv2.contourArea()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to isolate the rectangular contour.
3. **Perform perspective transform**. Next we perform contour approximation with [`cv2.contourArea()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to obtain the rectangular contour. Finally we utilize [`imutils.perspective.four_point_transform`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) to actually obtain the bird's eye view of the image.

---

Binary image

[image]

Result

[image]

To actually extract the text, take a look at

1. [Use pytesseract OCR to recognize text from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-ocr-to-recognize-text-from-an-image/60161328#60161328)
2. [Cleaning image for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159257/cleaning-image-for-ocr/59166202#59166202)
3. [Detect text area in an image using python and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771263/detect-text-area-in-an-image-using-python-and-opencv/58127373#58127373)

Code

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
import cv2
import numpy

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and sort for largest contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
displayCnt = None

for c in cnts:
    # Perform contour approximation
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        displayCnt = approx
        break

# Obtain birds' eye view of image
warped = four_point_transform(image, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("warped", warped)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 3):

To Solve this problem you can also use minAreaRect api in opencv which will give you a minimum area rotated rectangle with an angle of rotation. You can then get the rotation matrix and apply warpAffine for the image to straighten it. I have also attached a colab notebook which you can play around on.

Colab notebook : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SKxrWJBOHhGjEgbR2ALKxl-dD1sXIf4h?usp=sharing

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

def rotate_image(image, angle):
  image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
  rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
  result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  return result

img = cv2.imread("/content/sxJzw.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2_imshow(thresh)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_countour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
binary_mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest_countour], 0, 1, -1)
new_img = img * np.dstack((binary_mask, binary_mask, binary_mask))
minRect = cv2.minAreaRect(largest_countour)
rotate_angle = minRect[-1] if minRect[-1] < 0 else -minRect[-1]
new_img = rotate_image(new_img, rotate_angle)
cv2_imshow(new_img)
```